# php -how to solve Disk quota exceeded with some cpnel issue

Tags: php, session, phpmyadmin, cpanel, whm

When open my web-site in browser I am getting this error

> Warning: session_start():
>   open(/tmp/sess_4ac970943e0742367f5435e868cbcd5c, O_RDWR) failed: Disk
>   quota exceeded (122) in
>   /home/beahmer/public_html/oc-includes/osclass/core/Session.php on line
>   51

I cannot open my phpmyadmin from CPanel. When I am going to open phpMyadmin paage it show me this error 
[image]

In my CPanel Dashboard I am getting this error

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can ask your hosting provider to increase disk quota limit.

**If you have access to WHM**

1) Login to WHM. 
2) Click on the Account Functions icon (or section heading in the side column). 
3) Click on the Quota Modification icon (or link in the side column) . 
4) Select the domain or the user of the account. 
5) Click the Modify button. 
6) Enter the new value (in megabytes). 
7) Click the Change button.

Comment: You cannot change quota from cPanel.

Comment: i have acess to my cpanel . but when i am trying to access using those user name and password login is invalied

Comment: It seems that you have shared hosting account. There is nothing you can do from your end. You should contact your hosting provider.

Answer (score 0):

For Virtualmin

1. click "Edit Virtual Server"
2. the section labeled "Quotas and limits"
3. you can change the quotas to whatever you like, and then save it.