# failed to open stream: Disk quota exceeded

Tags: laravel

I have this issue when ill load my code already a lot of space in my  server still showing this

> file_put_contents(/home/mblood/public_html/storage/framework/sessions/dkNnP820TCXBj3XLGJ7x6GutSLmiIhv0PBpIeWtD):
>   failed to open stream: Disk quota exceeded

Comment: obviously you need more disk space on server....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [php -how to solve Disk quota exceeded with some cpnel issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33686065/php-how-to-solve-disk-quota-exceeded-with-some-cpnel-issue)

Answer (score 2):

The first solution:
cache clearing .

The second solution :
Manually delete "laravel.log" file in /storage/logs directory.